# I need to know how to add pagination with vue.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, vue.js

I Have html+javascript that requests from mongodb database some games(game1,2,3,4,5,6)just simple database with alot of games.
I want to know how via vue.js i can do pagination that per page show 4games.?

```
const SEARCH = new Vue({
el: '#search',
data: {
    query: {
        name: '',
        max_price:0,
        game_category:'',
        game_publisher:'',


    },
    games: [] // current list of games. we re-fill this array after search
},
methods: {
    btn_search: function () {
        // now we know that this.query is our search critearia object
        // so we can do fetch, and will do.

        fetch('/search?json=' + JSON.stringify(this.query))
            .then((response) => { //as you remember - res is a buffer.
                return response.text();
            })
            .then((text_response) => {
                console.log('got response!');
                let games_from_server = JSON.parse(text_response);

                this.games.splice(0, this.games.length); //it will remove all elemtns from array remove all elemtns from array

                // and add games from server one by one.
                for (let i = 0; i < games_from_server.length; i++) {
                    this.games.push(games_from_server[i]);
                }

            });



       console.log(this.query);
    }

}
```

});

console.log('pew?');

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a client-side pagination you can do it this way:

In your data add `currentPage: 1` and `gamesPerPage`:

```
data() {
   return {
      currentPage: 1,
      gamesPerPage: 4,
      games: []
   }
}
```

then add a computed property `paginatedGames` which is your `games` property split into pages, a `currentPageGames` property which filters games in current page and `changePage` method which changes your page:

```
computed: {
   paginatedGames() {
      let page = 1;
      return [].concat.apply(
         [], 
         this.games.map( (game, index) => 
            index % this.gamesPerPage ? 
               [] : 
               { page: page++, games: this.games.slice(index, index + this.gamesPerPage)}
         )
       );
   },
   currentPageGames() {
      let currentPageGames = this.paginatedGames.find(pages => pages.page == this.currentPage);
        return currentPageGames ? currentPageGames.games : [];
   }
},
methods {
   changePage(pageNumber) {
      if(pageNumber !== this.currentPage)
           this.currentPage = pageNumber;
   }
}
```

Complete example: http://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/217989/

However, if your database has lots of games, it might be a better idea to implement a server-side pagination and fetch games only for requested page.

Comment: You should not modify state, or component variables within a computed property. Computed properties are meant to be derived values.